# Dynamic Context Menu on WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I have an application with a WPF treeview with a node hierarchy. I have to display a context menu for the one or more selected nodes. When one or more nodes are selected, a collection in my viewmodel gets populated with all those selected nodes.

I have a collection of menuitems binded to my treeview contextmenu. I only want this binding to be evaluated when user right clicks on the node(or nodes).

To be bit more specific here is what I want:

- User clicks on one or more menu items to select them
- He right clicks for bringing up the contextmenu, I need my contextmenu biding(MenuItems) to be evaluated at this point in time and not while the user clicks on each menu itmes as is happening now.

Below is my code:

```
<TreeView MinWidth="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviors1:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>   
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"  Visibility="{Binding ShowContextMenu, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuCommand}"/>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

And my ViewModel:

```
internal class MyViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private readonly IContextMenuProvider _contextMenuProvider;

    public MyViewModel(IContextMenuProvider contextMenuProvider)
    {
        _contextMenuProvider = contextMenuProvider;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Getting menu items");
            return GetMenuItems();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<INodeViewModel> _selectedNodes;

    public ObservableCollection<INodeViewModel> SelectedNodes
    {
        get { return _selectedNodes; }
        set
        {
            _selectedNodes = value;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Setting selected nodes");

            foreach (var nodeViewModel in _selectedNodes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(nodeViewModel.Name);
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedNodes);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShowContextMenu);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MenuItems);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            var canDisplay = _contextMenuProvider.GetMenuItemsByNodeContext(SelectedNodes);
                return !canDisplay.IsNullOrEmpty();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IMenuItem> GetMenuItems()
    {
        var items = _contextMenuProvider.GetAllMenuItems(SelectedNodes);
        var menuItems = new ObservableCollection<IMenuItem>(items);
        return menuItems;
    }
}
```

The issues I'm facing is: I dont know at which point should I fetch the menu items, should I do it while selectednodes collection is getting populated  or on right click by user? I want either one of them happening ideally during the right click, question how do I refresh my treeview contextmenu bindings while right clicking a node on the treeview?

Note: I have a selected property on the NodeViewModel for selection purposes.

Thanks,
-Mike